# How to disable Running Header & Footer using tagpdf

Tags: lualatex-dev, tagpdf

How to deactivate Running Header and Footer using tagpdf.sty file.

\DocumentMetadata
{
testphase={title,table}, pdfversion=1.7, lang=en-UK, pdfstandard=a-4,pdfstandard=ua-2,uncompress
}

Comment: depends on how you activate them. tagpdf doesn't add headers. The normal way would be \pagestyle{empty}.

Comment: Unrelated but for ua-2 you must use pdfversion=2.0.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I need running header but no need to read.

Comment: if you use the right testphase then this is automatic, but only with title and table you don't get tagging.

Comment: which testphase can i use?

Comment: `testphase={phase-III,title,table}`